# UIAlertController can't be called by other class

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to write a class for parsing xml. I want to show Alert when some error occurs.
Here is my code:

Parse.swift

```
func parserXml(xmlUrl:String,completionHandler:([(staID: String, staName: String, ava: String, unava: String)]->Void)?)->Void{

    self.paraserCompletionHandler = completionHandler
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: xmlUrl)!)
    let urlConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    urlConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
    urlConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60
    let urlSession = NSURLSession(configuration: urlConfig, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    let task = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data,response,error)->Void in
        if error != nil{
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            if (error?.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut || error?.code == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet){
                let vc = ViewController()
                vc.alertView()
            }
        }else{
            let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data!)
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
        }            
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
func alertView(){
    var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    var okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When I run my app, my app crash and show error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

EDIT: Xcode Stop at

```
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I guess the reason is alertController in ViewController.swift is called by Parse.swift

can anyone resolve this question? thx

Comment: Xcode should stop on the problematic line when the app crashes. Which line is?

Comment: stop at  self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw a [custom exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493173/how-to-create-custom-exception-in-objective-c) in Parse.swift and catch it in ViewController.swift. You could create a custom class (NSException) where you establish this `exception` and implement it into both.

Here's [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363612/try-catch-block-in-objective-c) handling the exception if it is unfamiliar.

```
if error {
    print(error?.localizedDescription)
    if (error?.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut ||
        error?.code == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet){
        @throw [[CustomException alloc] initWithName:@"Title"
                                              reason:@"Message"
                                            userInfo:nil];
    }
} else{
            let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data!)
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
        }
```

In `ViewController` `try()` calling parserXml(...) then in the `catch()` that's when you give the alert this way you can throw multiple exceptions in `parserXml(...)` which would make this next statement perfect if you were have multiple error types you'd like to display.

```
catch (YourCustomException *ce) {
    alertController = UIAlertController(title: ce.name,
                                      message: ce.message,
                               preferredStyle: .Alert)
}
```

Comment: I use another way to do what I want, but I think your answer is also useful. thanks for your help :)